# Activate render man in Maya 2012

Tags: python, maya, mel

For some reason my render window in Maya doesn't work. Is there any way I can activate it by using MEL script or Python? I think it's disabled.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a error message? Do you load a old scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps: http://3dg.me/3d-graphics/maya/fix-for-maya-2012-error-setparent-object-renderview-not-found

You can delete (save it before delete) your prefs directory. It helps sometimes